# How to re-show this vim's welcome screen?

Tags: vim

I love seeing this screen when I start up Vim, but when I type a character the screen disappears.

Is there a command I can use to manually show it again?

[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could issue the command:

```
:intro
```

Comment: This works but also I could see this nasty "Press ENTER or type command to continue" which was not shown at the real startup. How to get rid of it?

Answer (score 6):

The [`:intro` command](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/starting.html#:intro) displays the welcome screen.